# Dependency not found: please run 'pip3 install pyserial'

Tags: python, pip

So I have been trying to run a program of a ti 84 plus ce. It asks to run this program bridge.py with the command python3 bridge.py. Python version is 3.9, pyserial version is 3.5 (c:\users\megam\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pyserial-3.5-py3.9.egg (3.5)) and pip version is 22.3.1. I have installed everything but whenever I try that command it always gives me this error 'Dependency not found: please run 'pip3 install pyserial'. If anyone knows how to solve this, really thank you.

I tried reistalling and installing a bunch of times but probably messed up things even more.

Comment: `pip3 install pyserial` What happens when you run that command?

Comment: it says it has already been installed: Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users\megam\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pyserial-3.5-py3.9.egg (3.5)

Comment: It sounds like you have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your computer. pip installed the module for one version of Python, but you're using a different version of Python to run the code.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `python3 --version`